# Rx Unit testing takeWhile

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, rx-java

I have the following method that I have not clue how can I make its unit testing:

```
private Completable checkMachineStatus(){
        return deviceDriver.getNotification(new OperationKey("HMINotification"),
                HMI_DESCRIPTION, REQUIRED_HMI_BYTE_NUMBER)
                .takeWhile(data -> {
                    MachineStatus status = MachineStatus.getMachineState(data.array()[MACHINE_STATUS_CHECK_POSITION]);
                    return status != MachineStatus.READY;
                }).ignoreElements();
    }
```

getNotification method is an Observable

What I am trying to do is this:

```
    @Test
    public void testPowerBrewSuccess() {
        when(deviceDriver.getNotification(any(OperationKey.class), any(CharacteristicDescription.class), any(Integer.class)))
                .thenReturn(byteBufferObservable);
        when(byteBufferObservable.takeWhile(any())).thenReturn(predicateObservable);
        when(predicateObservable.ignoreElements()).thenReturn(Completable.complete());

        brew.brew(BrewParameters.POWER).test();
        verify(deviceDriver).getNotification(any(OperationKey.class), any(CharacteristicDescription.class), any(Integer.class));
    }
```

But is failing while doing the takeWhile operation.

Comment: You are trying to mock the entire observer chain. What results did you expect and what did you get?

Comment: it is just failing in the line `when(byteBufferObservable.takeWhile(any())).thenReturn(predicateObservable);` what is inside takeWhile should be something else that any but I am not sure what it should be or how I have to proceed

Comment: I strongly suggest your don't try to mock the observer chain. Either mock just the `getNotification()` method with a usable return value so you can test `checkMachineStatus()` or mock `checkMachineStatus()` if you are testing its callers. Mocking the RxJava methods is nearly pointless